# Sending email via gmail smtp ubuntu 18.04 php

Tags: php, email, postfix, gmail, smtp

In RoR in order to send email from the application, we simply provide smtp settings for gmail and the server start using them to send emails.

I have bought [Active Super Shop Multi-vendor CMS](https://codecanyon.net/item/active-super-shop-multivendor-cms/12124432) which provides a section to provide smtp settings. I add the smtp settings for gmail and on a server provided by godaddy hosting, the setup seems to work just fine and starts sending emails. On a server setup on AWS I do not get the emails and I am not even sure where to look.

Can someone guide me where to start or what app i might be missing. Initially I did not have postfix installed but now i have it installed. But I do not think I have it configured right.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to install `sendmail` and `php-mail` packages for the emails on PHP to work

Comment: are there any configurations involved?

Comment: No, default ones work fine for sending mails via PHP. They can end up in SPAM, though, so look the folder up after a minute or two If you're not getting the email into your inbox.